# $Z=X+Y$ is Gaussian, $X$ & $Y$ are not, $X$ & $Y$ are independent. Example?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, convolution

Suppose $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables, with $Z=X+Y$.

Suppose further that $Z$ is Gaussian, $X$ and $Y$ are non-Gaussian, and that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

What distribution could $X$ and $Y$ have? Any example would do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such $X$ and $Y$ exist.

A well-known characterization of the Gaussian distribution is given by [Cramer's theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=OXkg-LvRgjUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA525#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> **Theorem.** If the sum $X+Y$ of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ is normally distributed and these variables are independent, then each of $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed.

Comment: I dimly remembered there being a result to do with this. I thought I must have imagined it though!