# Condition for the sum/difference of random variables to be normally distributed.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Consider two random variables, $X \sim N(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$ and $Y \sim (\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$. It is known that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then the sum/difference of $X$ and $Y$ will be normally distributed, such that $X \pm Y \sim N(\mu_X \pm \mu_Y, \sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y)$.

However, is the converse true? Supposing we have $2$ independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $X \pm Y $ is normally distributed, is it then true that $X$ and $Y$ must both be normally distributed? In other words, is it possible for the sum/difference of $2$ non-normally distributed random variables to be normally distributed?

Comment: It is a well known theorem that if $X,Y$ are i.i.d. and  $X + Y$, $X-Y$ are normally distributed so are $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Is there a specific name for this theorem? Where can I read up about it?

Comment: There are what are called 'Charactriztion Theorems'  for various distributions. Lukac's book on Characterisitic functions  has this theorem for normal distribution It requires a heavy doze of Complex Analysis.

Comment: Remark: There are trivial counterexamples like $Y=0$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3370711/321264. See [Cramer's decomposition theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=OXkg-LvRgjUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA525#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Thank you! This helped!